# Conformal mapping of two annuli to the punctured unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, conformal-geometry

What is the general procedure for finding a holomorphic bijection from the region $ \Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z - a| > 1, |z + a| > 1 \}$ to the punctured unit disc?

Comment: I do not know why that requirement but it should be fine with $|a| \leq 1$. I would be okay if I see a generalizable approach for the case $a = i$.